# Integrating caroussel in shared layout with partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, view

Newbie in MVC and I like the thing :)
I'm trying to integrate a slider in a shared layout by calling the controller of the caroussel and its view. But it doesn't seem to work for the moment. It works fine in the view of the slider (with the unadapted shared layout) but it doesn't work when calling it as a partial view.
It seems I'm overlooking something.

Is there something interfering with javascript?

### Here's my code of the shared layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/responsiveslides.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ons Team", "OnsTeam", "Personeels")</li>
                    <!-- Import partial menu -->
                    @Html.Action("TopNav", "Menu")
                    <!-- End partial menu -->
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Begin Slider -->
    @Html.Action("TopSlider", "Slider")
    <!-- End Slider -->

    <div class="container body-content">


        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
```

### Code of View

```
@model IEnumerable<Project_Assupen.Models.Slider>

<ul class="rslides">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li><img src="@item.ImageFileName" class="rslides"></li>
    }
```

Greetz, W

Comment: The `</ul>` closing tag is missing in the partial view?

Comment: The closing tag wasn't missing. Found the problem. In the controller the return was set to 'View' and should be... 'PartialView'. I will never forget that anymore.